# jQuery: How to add automatically LI elements from each heading in article

Tags: jquery, wordpress, post, scrollspy

I would like to implement the "ScrollSpy" (I use Materialize) in each blog post. The best implementation I think is with jQuery. However, I am struggling to make it dynamic. So, far I have this code.

```
$('body.single .entry-content').append('<div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2"><ul class="section table-of-contents"></ul></div>');

var h2 = $('.entry-content').find('h2').text();
var h3 = $('.entry-content').find('h3').text();

$('ul.table-of-contents').append("<li><a href='#" +h2 +"'>" +h2 +"</a></li>");
$('ul.table-of-contents').append("<li><a href='#" +h3 +"'>" +h3 +"</a></li>");
```

How can I make it dynamic based on number of h2, h3, h4, etc. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through the header elements and then add the `li` elements like:

```
var html = '';
$('.entry-content').find('h2, h3, h4, h5').each(function() {
  var header = $(this).text();
  html += "<li><a href='#" + header + "'>" + header + "</a></li>";
});
$('ul.table-of-contents').append(html);
```

Comment: Flawless. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following block

```
$('body.single .entry-content').append('<div class="col hide-on-small-only m3 l2"><ul class="section table-of-contents"></ul></div>');

$(".entry-header h2, .entry-header h3").each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this), ID = "header" + index;
    $this.attr("id", ID);
    $("ul.table-of-contents").append(
        $("<li/>").append($("<a/>").attr("href", "#" + ID).text(h2.text());
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

Say you'd want to go up to h4

```
For (var i=0;i<=4;i++){
var hTag= 'h' + i.toString();
hText=    $('.entry-content').find('hTag').text();
$('ul.table-of-contents').append("<li><a href='#" +hText +"'>" +hText +"</a></li>");

}
```